# Remove extra spacing around formulas

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

When I make formulas (`ctrl + alt + =`) in LibreOffice Writer, they have a bit of extra space on either side. How do I remove this?

Comment: If there are any better ways/shortcuts, please post

Answer (score 1):

### Removing the spacing from one formula

If you just want to remove the spacing from one formula object:

1. Right-click on the formula
2. Select "Properties..." from the context menu, or press `P`
3. Select the "Wrap" tab
4. Under the "**Spacing**" header, you can adjust the spacing surrounding the object on all sides

### Removing the spacing from all formulas

This also sets the default

1. Navigate to the styles menu (`alt + y`) or press `f11` and skip step 2
2. Click "Manage Styles" (It's on the bottom for me (or `alt + y` again))
3. Click the "Frame Styles" button
   [image: "Manage Styles" menu]
4. Right-click "Formula"
5. Click "Modify..."
6. "Wrap" tab
7. Adjust spacing on all sides under "**Spacing**" header